# Left Side menu with TAbbar in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to implement the Left Side menu. On my top of screen, there is a TabBar with a menu button.

When the menu tab bar button click, the left Side menu will open.

I search a lot for this but all of them uses the Navigation Controller instead of TAbbar.
 I try so many custom controls & SASlideview but don't understand how to work with tabbar.

[image]

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self navigationController],
                                          [self navigationController], nil]];

SideMenuViewController *leftSideMenuController = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] init];
SideMenuViewController *rightSideMenuController = [[SideMenuViewController alloc] init];
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController]
                                                leftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuController
                                                rightMenuViewController:rightSideMenuController];

self.window.rootViewController = container;
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Create your own custom Tabbar as well left panel option if you want to such kind of customization. No one is going to code for you and also  show something that you tried on your own.

Comment: @Leena, I am not telling to code but give me some reference, if you have.